# Very Large Text that just disappeared in IDLE PyCharm

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-idle

I Have This Algorithm Below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for link in soup.select('div.sg-actions-list__hole > a[href*="/tarefa"]'):
    ref=link.get('href')
    rt = ('https://brainly.com.br'+str(ref))
    p.append(rt)
print(p)

for url in p:
    r = requests.get(url).text
    time.sleep(10)
    print(r)
```

Which basically imprints the source code of the page.

My Problem Is Not About the Algorithm, but About IDLE because when you print the page source code it is too big that some parts of the `HTML` end up disappearing, my question is if there is any solution to this.

Comment: Maybe you can save it in a file.

Comment: Saving on a Variable It Would Make it Easy to Filter With BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Your code is missing an initialization of p: 'p = []' most likely.  I really don't know what you mean by 'disappearing'.  I know that super long lines are bad for the tkinter Text that IDLE uses, but have never in a decade seen 'disappear'.  In any case, run your code directly with python and see if that changes behavior.  IDLE is intended for learning and development, not routine production.

Comment: Disappear in the sense that the text is so large that parts of it are not showing up, like not being redenected

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guess what 'redenected' is supposed to mean.  In any case, please specify your OS and OS version, and how many characters and lines your are trying to print ('len(p), count(  Also, try to reproduce the problem without involving beautiful soup, a 3rd party module, by generating the text in your program.

For instance, on Windows 10 with 3.9.0a1, I can print a 100000 line text.

```
>>> def f(n):
    nl = '\n'
    s=('a'*60 + nl)*n
    print(f"s has {len(s)} chars, {s.count(nl)} lines")
    print(s)

>>> f(100000)
s has 6100000 chars, 100000 lines

[Squeezed text (100000 lines).]  # Reverse text box after about 1/2 minute.
```

Squeezing large output was introduced late 2018.  It protects against the freeze effect of long lines.  As should be explained in the IDLE doc, squeezed text can copied to the clipboard, viewed in a separate window, or expanded in the shell.

Comment: Using SublimeText the total and print and display text, unlike pycharm, for example, it does not see the image, filters the images, so it is a small text that does not appear.